# Resolving promise arrays in the most optimised way

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 3 arrays loaded with some promises. What is the best and optimised way to resolve all these promises?

Comment: Hi, you can try `Promise.all([...a, ...b, ...c])`

Comment: Promises instances can't be directly resolved or rejected. Unless your question is wrong, you can't do what you're asking. Generally, at the time of promise creation you'll be able to get resolve/reject methods that can be used in a lot of different ways.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Promise All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). It fullfills when all the promises are passed.

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Promise.all for this.

Use this link for reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: The question is how to resolve existent promises, not how to create a new promise that resolves when the others are resolved.